# Existence of a normalized vector, far from proper closed subspace.

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Say we have a normed vector space $(E, \|\cdot\|)$, and a proper closed subspace $F\subsetneq E$, I want to prove the following:

$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0), (\exists e \in E) : \|e\|=1  \text{  and  }  d(e,F) \geq 1 - \varepsilon $$

Where $d(e,F)= \inf\limits_{y \in F} \|e-y\|$.

I started proving the following fact:

Given $x \in E, \alpha \geq 1$, $\exists f \in F $ such that $\|x-f\|\leq\alpha \cdot d(x,F)$

Which is true by definition of $d$ as an infimum, because: $$ (\forall \varepsilon>0), (\exists f_{\varepsilon} \in F): d(x,F)\leq d(x,f_{\varepsilon})\leq d(x,F)+\varepsilon$$
And taking $\varepsilon = (\alpha - 1)\cdot d(x,F)$ we conclude.

So trying to use the last fact, let $\varepsilon >0,$ we define for $\bar{x} \notin F$ and $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ to be determined, the $f\in F$ such that $ \|\bar{x}-f\|\leq \alpha\cdot d(\bar{x},F)$, then I don't know how to follow.

Mostly I don't know how to link $\bar{x}-f$ with the $e\in E $ that I'm trying to find, I could normalize, but I can't figure out where to get the inequality I'm looking for, my guess would be through fixing $\alpha = \frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}$ or something like that, but inequalities I manage to get are upper bounds.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $F$ a sub_space_ as in the title or just a sub_set_ as in the problem statement. If it''s  just a subset, this is clearly false. If it's a subspace: Why do you think it's true?

Comment: I meant it to be a subspace, just edited it.

It was a question on an exam from my Analysis course last year, I was fiddling around with it since i couldn't answer it correctly at the time.

Comment: As for my intuition, It should be true since as $F$ is a proper subspace, there's "directions" not included on $F$, therefore if one of this missing directions is "orthogonal" we can choose that one, if none are we can move just enough in some of these directions so we are as far as we can from the subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to follow trough with David's help.

So we choose $y=\frac{\bar{x}-f}{\|\bar{x}-f\|}$, where f is given as in the property stated in the question body, for $\alpha =\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}$.

Clearly $\|y\|=1$, so we compute it's distance to $F$.

$$d(y,F) = \inf\limits_{g \in F} \|y-g\| = \inf\limits_{g \in F} \left\|\frac{\bar{x}-f}{\|\bar{x}-f\|}-g\right\| $$

Lets focus on a fixed $g \in F:$

$$=  \left\| \frac{\bar{x}}{\|\bar{x}-f\|} -\left( \frac{f}{\|\bar{x}-f\|} + g \right) \right\| =\frac{1}{\|\bar{x} -f\|}  \left\| \bar{x}-g' \right\| $$

Where $g'=f+\|\bar{x}-f\|\cdot g \in F$, because its a subspace.

$$\geq \frac{1}{\|\bar{x}-f\|}d(x,F) \geq \frac{1}{\alpha} \geq 1-\varepsilon$$

Where the last two inequalities follow from choice of $f$ and $\alpha$, since g was arbitrary, we conclude:

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists y \in E : \|y\| =1 \text{ and } d(y,F)\geq 1-\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $d(x,F)>0$ for $x\notin F$ and $d(tx,F)=td(x,F)$ there exists $x_1$ with $d(x_1,F)=1$. Choose $a\in F$ with $||x_1-a||$ close to $1$. Now $x=x_1-a$ is almost the point you want...